# Can't match regex with sed

Tags: regex, bash, replace, sed

I'm trying to match a pattern `(\^|\~?)(\d|x|\*)+\.(\d|x|\*)+\.(\d|x|\*)+` with `sed` without luck.
The file I'm running through is this:

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "some desc",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.0",
    "radium": "^0.16.2",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^1.1.10",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-timeago": "^2.2.1",
    "sprintf": "^0.1.5",
    "smoothscroll": "~0.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.3.26",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "~12.0.1",
    "console-stamp": "^0.2.0",
    "estraverse-fb": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "lodash": "4.5.1",
    "lodash.assign": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash.isfunction": "^3.0.8",
    "lodash.reduce": "^4.3.0",
    "node-sass": "3.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.29.4",
    "react-intl": "2.1.0",
    "reactify": "1.1.1",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "vinyl": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.4.0",
    "jsx-to-string": "~0.2.11"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "pkg-save": "~1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "someurl"
  },
  "author": "authorname",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

As you can see in regexr it matches the desired pattern (also matching "version" but that's another issue I'll tackle later):
http://regexr.com/3e324

I'm invoking invoking sed with the following command:
`cat package.json | sed 's/(\^|\~?)(\d|x|\*)+\.(\d|x|\*)+\.(\d|x|\*)+/Hello/g' -r`

For the sake of brevity, it outputs something like (ie. unfiltered input):

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
...
```

It should replace all digits with "Hello".
What am I doing wrong?
Something to do with bad flags (I've tried `/gm`)
or not using the correct regex engine (I'm passing the `-r` option to utilize extended regex)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your `sed` problem (sorry) but I just want to mention if you are doing some JSON work like this, you might want to use a tool better suited for it like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: Thanks, this might be what I need!
I need a tool that can directly manipulate package.json files and where I have full control over what's being changed.

Comment: I've fixed it by using `[0-9]` rather than `\d`. (I still second using `jq` if you handle a lot of JSON)

Comment: Great, thanks @Aaron. I thought passing `-r` would enable sed to recognize the `\d` character class. I think I'll go ahead and use `jq` anyway for better manipulation.
Feel free to write an answer and I'll mark it as approved.

Comment: All tools use different regexp flavors with different caveats/constraints. Using some online regexp validator is useless as it provides no assurance whatsoever that a given regexp will work in whatever tool you want to use it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While POSIX regular expression support some named character classes, like `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:alnum:]]`, they do not support shorthand classes such as `\d` and `\w`.

Some GNU extensions bring shorthand classes support, but they are restricted to a few of them, `\w`, `\W`, `\s` and `\S` according to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html).

By replacing the `\d` in your regular expression to `[0-9]` I was able to transform your document. The regular expression becomes `(\^|\~?)([0-9]|x|\*)+\.([0-9]|x|\*)+\.([0-9]|x|\*)+`, or better `[~^]([0-9x*]+\.){2}[0-9x*]` (thanks Ed Morton !).

As a side note, your command could be rewritten to the following, which does not use `cat` :

```
sed -E 's/[~^]([0-9x*]+\.){2}[0-9x*]/Hello/' package.json
```

And as noted by Matt, you'd be better off using a JSON parser such as `jq`.

Comment: Your script is currently GNU sed-specific due to `-r` instead of `-E` to enable EREs and you're escaping characters that don't need to be escaped, e.g. `~` and the RE segments like `([0-9]|x|\*)+` are unnecessarily long/complicated, etc.. I understand that's because you copied the OPs non-functioning script but it'd be good to clean it up - the whole thing can be written more portably as just (untested but will be close if not exactly right) `sed -E 's/[~^]([0-9x*]+\.){2}[0-9x*]/Hello/'`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tested it (with GNU sed though) and updated my answer. I didn't knew `-E` existed, it doesn't even appear in my `man sed` !

Comment: Yes. It's supported in BSD sed and in newer GNU seds as an alternative to -r but the GNU folks haven't updated the documentation [yet].