# Replacing all values of multiple JSON objects with jq

Tags: json, foreach, key-value, jq, map-function

I'm trying to replace all values of a JSON object with `*` (asterisk character) using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "project-desc",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.0",
    "radium": "^0.16.2",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap-sweetalert": "^1.1.10",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-timeago": "^2.2.1",
    "sprintf": "^0.1.5",
    "smoothscroll": "~0.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.3.26",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "console-stamp": "^0.2.0",
    "estraverse-fb": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.5.1",
    "lodash.assign": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash.isfunction": "^3.0.8",
    "lodash.reduce": "^4.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.29.4",
    "react-intl": "^2.1.0",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "vinyl": "^1.1.0",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.4.0",
    "jsx-to-string": "~0.2.11"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "pkg-save": "~1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "mygiturl"
  },
  "author": "authorname",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I want to replace all values of the `dependencies`, `devDependencies` and `optionalDependencies` objects with asterisk, like so (abbreviated example below):

```
...
"devDependencies": {
        "babel": "*",
        "babelify": "*",
        "browserify": "*",
        "console-stamp": "*",
...
```

Here's the filter I'm using:
`.dependencies, .devDependencies, .optionalDependencies | .foreach .[] as $item ([]; $item = "*")`
Passed in the command line as:
`cat package.json | jq '.dependencies, .devDependencies, .optionalDependencies | .foreach .[] as $item ([]; $item = "*")'`

It's returning an error though, and not the desired result:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting IDENT
.dependencies, .devDependencies, .optionalDependencies | .foreach .[] as $item ([]; $item = "*")
                                                                   ^
1 compile error
```

More than just being a syntax error, I'm sure it's only manipulating the top-level items and not each key-value pair within the objects which is what I intend to do.

References and related questions:

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#foreach
- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)
- [Can't match regex with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103215/cant-match-regex-with-sed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight-forward way to accomplish the task would probably be to use the following filter:

`.dependencies |= map_values("*")
| .devDependencies |= map_values("*")
| .optionalDependencies |= map_values("*")`

To avoid the repetition:

`(.dependencies, .devDependencies, .optionalDependencies) |= map_values("*")`

Answer (score 4):

You could update all in one fell swoop by taking advantage of the comma operator.  To update all values to `"*"`, you could do this:

```
.["dependencies", "devDependencies", "optionalDependencies"] |= map_values("*")
```