# Why doesn't sed respect the simple regex?

Tags: sed

- My text:`mmhmmh here_is_you 05451ab8 888`
- My regex: `mmhmmh \w* ([ab0-9]*) \d*`
- My sed command: `echo "mmhmmh here_is_you 05451ab8 888" | sed -n 's/mmhmmh \w* \([ab0-9]*\) \d*/\1/p'`
- Result: `05451ab8888` instead of `05451ab8`

Why doesn't sed respect my regex? I checked and my regex should correctly select the expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't \`\d\` work in regular expressions in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671293/why-doesnt-d-work-in-regular-expressions-in-sed) and [Can't match regex with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39103215/3776858)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18514135/bash-regular-expression-cant-seem-to-match-s-s-etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Cyrus points out with the comment link, `\d` does gives problems, use `[0-9]`

```
echo "mmhmmh here_is_you 05451ab8 888" | sed -n 's/mmhmmh [a-zA-Z0-9_]* \([ab0-9]*\) [0-9]*/\1/p'
05451ab8
```

Or `[[:digit:]]`

```
echo "mmhmmh here_is_you 05451ab8 888" | sed -n 's/mmhmmh [[:alnum:]_]* \([ab0-9]*\) [[:digit:]]*/\1/p'
05451ab8
```

And as trpleee points out, do not use `\w` either.

Comment: You also need to fix `\w`. It might work in some `sed` variants but it is not portable.

Comment: @tripleee updated.